# find intersection between list and multiple lists from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am labeling data based on dict. the dict looks like  `{"tpoic1":["item1","item2"...],"tpoic2":["item1",....]....}`. I am reading this dict as dataframe with columns representing topics and list data. In my dataset I have a column named hashtags which in the form of a list like `["item1","item2",...]`.  I want to get if there are any intersections between the list of hashtags elements and one of the lists elements inside of the dict so that I can affect a topic to it. I used for loops solution but it takes forever. Any proposition on how can I optimize this with the power of dataframes?

Below is the dict that I am reading as a dataframe:

```
                 topic                                data
0                  war  [Ukraine, Nucléaire, Taliban, UkraineWar, Inva...
1   automotiveIndustry  [Tesla, Tennis, Stellantis, Audi, Industrie, A...
2               corona  [Corona, LongCovid, FFP2, Ungeimpfte, Santé, K...
3                sport  [Beijing2022, Eishockey, Formel1, Paralympics,...
4             politics  [Putin, GRAMMYs, GerhardSchröder, Präsident, D...
```

The code below is my solution but it will take 48h to run:

```
        for hashtag in sample["tweetHashtags"]:
            print("hashtag", hashtag)
            for key, row in clusters_df.iterrows():
                if hashtag in row.data:
                    print(row.topic)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?msclkid=0a82a5bcd08511ec95eae203578f88e9) your dataframe first:

```
clusters_df = clusters_df.explode("data", ignore_index=True)
```

You can then filter with one loop:

```
for hashtag in sample["tweetHashtags"]:
    print("hashtag", hashtag)
    print(clusters_df[clusters_df["data"] == hashtag]["topic"].unique())
```